# Why I can't populate my uiTableView with cells filled with data fetched from json?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my class:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ListOfEvents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView:UITableView?
    var items = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-100)
        self.tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self
        self.tableView?.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)
        print("aaa")
        getAllRequests()

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tableView.registerClass(SingleEventCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleEventCell

        let user:JSON =  JSON(self.items[indexPath.row])
       print(user["username"].description)
       // cell.username.text = user["username"].description
       // cell.descr.text = "ggg"
        print(cell)
        return cell
    }

    func getAllRequests() {
        print("getAllRequests")
        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRequests { json in
            let results = json//["username"]
            for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
                let user: AnyObject = JSON.object
                self.items.addObject(user)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.tableView?.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I try to fill my custom `UITableViewCell`s with data fetched from webservice. My problem is that:

```
print(user["username"].description) //that prints perfectly
```

but if I uncomment one of the lines below:

```
// cell.username.text = user["username"].description 
// cell.descr.text = "ggg"
```

I'm getting the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I suspect that I try to refer to the cells before they are initialized/visible for the algorithm, but if so - how can I prevent it? I'm using `viewDidLoad()` method but that doesn't change anything - the error is still the same.

How can I fix it?

====EDIT

@vadian suggested that it's a different table view in storyboard and in the code.I went with that advice and created an outlet for the tableview from storyboard and in all places in code changed the reference from `tableview` to newly created outlet:

import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

```
class ListOfEvents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tview: UITableView!
    var tableView:UITableView?
    var items = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-100)
        tview = UITableView(frame: frame)
        tview.dataSource = self
        tview.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(tview!)
        print("aaa")
        getAllRequests()

    }


    func tableView(tview: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tview: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tview.registerClass(SingleEventCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let cell = tview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleEventCell

        let user:JSON =  JSON(self.items[indexPath.row])
       print(user["username"].description)
       // cell.username.text = user["username"].description
        cell.descr.text = "ggg"
        print(cell)
        return cell
    }

    func getAllRequests() {
        print("getAllRequests")
        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRequests { json in
            let results = json
            for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
                let user: AnyObject = JSON.object
                self.items.addObject(user)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.tview.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But now when I run it I'm getting error;

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

here:

```
tview.dataSource = self
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: tableview is a part of ViewController http://i.imgur.com/dX5ASoL.png , it doesn't have any class assigned to it but the ViewController that contains it has assigned class `ListOfEvents`

Comment: The table view in the storyboard is not the table view in the code. Since you're using storyboard, what's the purpose to create everything in code?

Comment: @vadian please see my edit above

Comment: Have you connected the table view outlet in Interface Builder? Connect also data source and delegate in IB to omit the code lines. And at least comment out the code related to the programmatically created table view

Comment: @vadian, thanks for those suggestions, but can you tell me how to connect the datasource and delegate here?

Comment: In Interface Builder select the table view on the left side and the Connection Inspector (⌥⌘5) on the right. Beside the referencing outlet there are outlets for data source and delegate. Connect them to the controller instance. It might be still easier to use a `UITableViewController` because then everything is already prepared.

Comment: You're overriding your UITableView storyboard initialization. You need to remove this line: `tview = UITableView(frame: frame)`. Also, if you like, you can set your tableView delegate and data source in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem is this line:

```
tview = UITableView(frame: frame)
```

That is not how you create a table view in code. You must call its *designated initializer*, which is `initWithFrame:style:`. For example:

```
tview = UITableView(frame: frame, style: .Plain)
```

Note, however, that your code has various other problems that could also be an issue here. For example, this line:

```
let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-100)
```

That line depends on `self.view` having a frame, and a frame of sufficient size (i.e. more than 100 pixels in height). But you don't know this, because in `viewDidLoad`, `self.view` merely *exists* — it has not yet achieved its final frame because it has not yet been put into the interface and laid out. So that line is very risky at that point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, could you tell me how could I fix it?

Comment: No offense, but I'd discourage beginners from creating UI elements in code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you probably don't have your `username` and/or `descr` outlets set up correctly inside your `SingleEventCell`.

Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) to know how to connect your outlets correctly.

Comment: I do have them set up correctly, http://i.imgur.com/1RoA82C.png here's how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that your JSON object is not yet fetched at the time `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` wants to load it, therefor giving you an unexpectedly found nil error.

What You can do is this:

Create a new Delegate protocol:

```
protocol NetworkingDelegate {

    func didFinishLoadingData()
}
```

Create a class `Networking` where you put your API request in:

```
class Networking {

var networkingDelegate: NetworkingDelegate?


// (I am using Alamofire here so the function itself will differ a little.)

    func getAllRequests() {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "YOUR_API_ENDPOINT")
            .responseJSON { response in

                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    let jsonObject = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    User.populateUserDataSourceFromJSON(jsonObject)

                    self.dispatchAndRefresh()
                }
        }
    }
}


func dispatchAndRefresh() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if let delegate = self.networkingDelegate {
            delegate.didFinishLoadingData()
        }
    }
}
```

In your Modelclass have a function called populateUserDataSourceFromJSON

```
class User {

let name = String()
let age = Int()
//...

init() {
}


class func populateUserDataSourceFromJSON(json: JSON) {

    userDataSource = [User]()

    for (_, user): (String, JSON) in json {

        let currentUser = User()

        currentUser.name = user["name"].stringValue
        currentUser.age = user["age"].intValue
        //...

        userDataSource.append(currentUser)
    }
}
```

In your ViewController add the Delegate we created:

```
class ListOfEvents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NetworkingDelegate { 
    //...
```

create a reference of your Networking class:

```
let networking = Networking()
```

and set it's delegate to self:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    networking.networkingDelegate = self
    //...
```

Only thing left to do is to make your ViewController conform to the Delegate by implementing didFinishloadingData()

```
func didFinishLoadingData() {

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I hope this helps.